# Проблема с списком из цифр

Tags: python

Нужно что бы код работал с любым из чисел в скобках не зависимо. Я, скорее всего, не правильно записал цифры в скобки. Как записать это выражение правильно?

```
i = input(int(введи i))
if i == [1, 3, 4, 5]:
    print("работает")
else:
    print("не работает")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, результат функции `input` нужно приводить к целочисленному значению, т.е. `int(input("Введи i: "))`. Во-вторых, когда Вы пишите `i == [1, 3, 4, 5]`, Вы сравниваете введённое число со списком, результат всегда будет `False`.

Надо вот так:

```
i = int(input("Введи i: "))
foo = [1, 3, 4, 5]
if i in foo:
    print("работает")
else: 
    print("не работает")
```